# How to summarise data according to the AcctName in Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the follwing result. means sum up of all operatingcost and salaries etc. for that i have generated a query. which is written below

```
SELECT T1.[Segment_0],SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]) AS BUDGET, SUM(T3.[Debit]) AS DEBIT,
       AcctName = case when substring(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) between '6001' and '6027' then 'Operating Cost' 
                   when substring(T1.[Segment_0],1,4) between '5101' and  '5104' then 'Travel'
                   when substring (T1.[Segment_0],1,4) between '5001' and  '5001' then 'Salaries'
       else T1.[AcctName] end                         
FROM OBGT T0 INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode]=T1.[AcctCode] INNER JOIN OBGS T2 
ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account] INNER JOIN OASC T4 ON T1.[Project]=T4.[Code] 
GROUP BY T1.[AcctCode],T1.[Segment_0],T1.[AcctName]
```

I am expecting the following result from this query. but the values which i am getting are like the second table. please have a look on second table below first one.

`+--+-----------------+--+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
|  |      ITEM       |  |      BUDGET     | CURRENT BUDGET EXPENSES OCT         |
+--+-----------------+--+-----------------+-------------------------------------+
|  |                 |  |                 |                                     |
|  | Personnel Costs |  |                 |                                     |
|  | Salaries        |  |  $4,888,724.00  |  $383,153.89                        |
|  | Operatingcost   |  |  $540,218.00    |  $53,192.71                         |
+--+-----------------+--+-----------------+-------------------------------------+`

This is result which i am getting. please have a look below table

`+--------+----------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
|Segment_0|  AcctName     |  Budget   | CURRENT BUDGET EXPENSES OCT               |
+--------+----------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 500101 | Salaries       | 8898033    | 8898033    |                             |
| 500101 | Salaries       | 5459062    | 5459062    |                             |
| 500101 | Salaries       | 452569.6   | 452569.6   |                             |
| 600401 | Operating Cost | 4676556    | 4676556    |                             |
| 600401 | Operating Cost | 1242621.54 | 1242621.54 |                             |
| 600401 | Operating Cost | 882554.4   | 882554.4   |                             |
| 600401 | Operating Cost | 595670.4   | 595670.4   |                             |
+--------+----------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `T1.[Segment_0]` from your `SELECT` clause. Additionally, modify the `GROUP BY` clause and use the `CASE` expression instead:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]) AS BUDGET, 
    SUM(T3.[Debit]) AS DEBIT,
    AcctName = 
        CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) BETWEEN '6001' AND '6027' THEN 'Operating Cost' 
            WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) BETWEEN '5101' AND '5104' THEN 'Travel'
            WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.[Segment_0], 1 ,4) BETWEEN '5001' AND '5001' THEN 'Salaries'
            ELSE T1.[AcctName]
        END                         
FROM OBGT T0 
INNER JOIN OACT T1 
    ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 
    ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
INNER JOIN JDT1 T3 
    ON T1.[AcctCode] = T3.[Account]
INNER JOIN OASC T4 
    ON T1.[Project]=T4.[Code] 
GROUP BY
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) BETWEEN '6001' AND '6027' THEN 'Operating Cost' 
        WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.[Segment_0], 1, 4) BETWEEN '5101' AND '5104' THEN 'Travel'
        WHEN SUBSTRING(T1.[Segment_0], 1 ,4) BETWEEN '5001' AND '5001' THEN 'Salaries'
        ELSE T1.[AcctName]
    END
```